# Accessing angular scope value in controller from ng-repeat input box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was wondering how to get access to the $scope value from an input box, which happens to be in an ng-repeat, inside of the controller.

View

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
  <form ng-submit="addItem(item, $index)">
    <input ng-model="newItem.value" type="text"></input>
  </form>
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.addItem = function(item, index) {
  var itemVal = $scope.newItem.value;
  console.log(itemVal);
}
```

The main problem is that I can't access the value from either of the input boxes inside of the controller.

- code has been simplified for this quesiton

Really appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to have only one form or form per item?

Comment: It is a form per item, thanks

Comment: @ryan what do you mean by form per item?

Answer (score 0):

If you need one input per item, you need to keep one new model for each item somewhere.

If `items` is a list, you can keep these newItems in a separate list ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsalonen/j4rk2syk/)):

View

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
  <form ng-submit="addItem(item, $index)">
    <input ng-model="newItems[$index]" type="text"></input>
  </form>
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.newItems = [];
$scope.addItem = function(item, index) {
  var itemVal = $scope.newItems[index];
  console.log(itemVal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have only single value, which you want to show inside ng-repeat then Do initialize `newItem` inside controller like

```
$scope.newItem = {}
```

Because of `newItem` initialization on controller level, `ng-repeat` will never create a new child scope for it, it will reuse the one parent has created.

Comment: @ryan do you require anything more form us?